# Changing Marker Icon from Drawable folder in Eclipse Android

Tags: android, maps, marker

I got a problem on the code, and I don't know what's going wrong with it. 
Here it is:

```
mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
    .position(new LatLng(14.590230, 120.983149))
    .title("SM City Manila"))
    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
    .fromResource(R.drawable.blue));
```

The problem is on line 4, in which errors prints: `The method icon(BitmapDescriptor) is undefined for the type Marker.`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14599842/how-to-display-multiple-markers-with-different-icons-in-google-maps-android-api

Answer (score 1):

Try this .

```
 private static final LatLng MyPlace = new LatLng(14.590230, 120.983149);
              private Marker melbourne = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                                        .position(MyPlace)
                                        .title("SM City Manila")                                                      
                                        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.blue)));
```

Comment: Thanks for answering but problem is solved by changing .icon to .setIcon

Comment: @user3340295 Good to hear .Enjoy Stackoverflow