# MarkerOptions icon programmatically

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers, google-maps-android-api-2

I want to put a drawable programatically to my MarkerOptions in Google maps. I get the icon like String and later I try to use it to put the icon of the MarkerOptions.

I am using this code:

```
String icono = mis_localizaciones.get(i).getIcon();
int id = getResources().getIdentifier(icono, "drawable", getPackageName());
Drawable drawable = getResources().getDrawable(id);
mi_marker.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(drawable));
```

But I can´t do like this because there is an issue in : `mis_markers.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(drawable));`

Can somebody help me? Thanks a lot

Comment: That there is a issue in the line that I have write in my question, I can´t use like this the drawable.

Comment: you need to pass `Bitmap` at `BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(drawable)`

Comment: And how can I do this in my code, thanks

Comment: What issue in that line?

Answer (score 1):

```
//make Sure icono String doesnt contain extension of file
// eg: flower.png is not a valid input for icono 
// eg  flower is valid input 
String icono = mis_localizaciones.get(i).getIcon();


int id = getResources().getIdentifier(icono, "drawable",getPackageName());
```

> ```
> // In id variable you aleady got drawable image refrence
> ```

```
 mi_marker.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(id));
```

Comment: Yes, but if I want youriconname become to variable?

Comment: i got your Question just a minute

Answer (score 0):

Follow below doc :-

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/marker

see below code to add marker on your map.

```
Marker melbourne = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                          .position(MELBOURNE)
                          .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_AZURE)));
```

see this

[How to display multiple markers with different icons in Google Maps Android API v2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14599842/how-to-display-multiple-markers-with-different-icons-in-google-maps-android-api)

Comment: Yes, but I am trying to put custom image on the marker programmatically

Comment: what do you mean by custom image?

Comment: Your code is with default marker of google maps, I want to use my images to put on the markers

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing up `BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource()` and `BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap()`. This is the correct use of `fromResource()`. It takes the resource id as the argument:

```
String icono = mis_localizaciones.get(i).getIcon();
int id = getResources().getIdentifier(icono, "drawable", getPackageName());           
mi_marker.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(id));
```